# How to init a double**?

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, double, allocation

I need to init/use a double ** (decleared in my header):

```
double **pSamples;
```

allocating (during the time) a matrix of NxM, where N and M are get from two function:

```
const unsigned int N = myObect.GetN(); 
const unsigned int M = myObect.GetM();
```

For what I learnt from heap and dynamic allocation, I need keyword `new`, or use STL `vector`, which will manage automatically allocate/free within the heap.

So I tried with this code:

```
vector<double> samplesContainer(M);
*pSamples[N] = { samplesContainer.data() };
```

but it still says I need a constant value? How would you allocate/manage (during the time) this matrix?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<double>> samplesContainer(M, std::vector<double>(N));` might be a good alternative to `double**`

Comment: Or a flat `std::vector` (`N * M` `double`) wrapped in a class to have the expected indexing.

Comment: `*pSamples[N] = { samplesContainer.data() };` won't allocate anything it is just assignment, and probably not the one you meant for. since it out of range.

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, but than I need to pass to a method a double**. So How can I convert later std::vector<std::vector<double>> samplesContainer(M, std::vector<double>(N)); to a double**?

Comment: Programming by guessing does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *old fashioned way* of initializing a pointer to a pointer, is correctly enough with the `new` operator, you would first initialize the the first array which is a pointer to doubles (`double*`), then you would iterate through that allocating the next pointer to doubles (`double*`).

```
double** pSamples = new double*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    pSambles[i] = new double[M];
}
```

The first new allocates an array of double pointers, each pointer is then assigned to the array of pointers allocated by the second `new`.

That is the old way of doing it, remember to release the memory again at some point using the `delete []` operator. However C++ provide a lot better management of sequential memory, such as a `vector` which you can use as either a vector of vectors, or simply a single vector capable of holding the entire buffer.

If you go the vector of vector way, then you have a declaration like this:

```
vector<vector<double>> samples;
```

And you will be able to reference the elements using the `.at` function as such: `samples.at(2).at(0)` or using the array operator: `samples[2][0]`.

Alternatively you could create a single `vector` with enough storage to hold the multidimensional array by simply sizing it to be `N * M` elements large. However this method is difficult to resize, and honestly you could have done that with `new` as well: `new double[N * M]`, however this would give you a `double*` and not a `double**`.

Comment: The single-`vector` is approach is far superior to anything else mentioned on this page, and there's no reason to think that a matrix needs to be trivially resized. I'm astounded to see so much `new` and double-pointers and vectors of vectors in these answers!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OP probably have to call a method which accepts `double**`, how can you do it with single vector?

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski: In that case, you can't. But a library taking `double**` would be extremely poor as that then near-_mandates_ O(N) dynamic allocations and awful memory locality. Hopefully that's not the case here, but the OP did not say.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes, the library I'm using take `double**`

Answer (score 1):

Use RAII for resource management:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> samplesContainer(M, std::vector<double>(N));
```

then for compatibility

```
std::vector<double*> ptrs(M);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != M; ++i) {
    ptrs[i] = samplesContainer[i].data();
}
```

And so pass `ptrs.data()` for `double**`.

Comment: What do you mean with "then for compatibility"? Can't just use `std::vector<std::vector<double>> samplesContainer(M, std::vector<double>(N));`? Tried this: `vector<vector<double>> samplesContainer(M, vector<double>(N)); pSamples = samplesContainer.data();` but can't assign it to my double**

Comment: @paizza: `samplesContainer.data()` is `std::vector<double>*`. your `double **` is done with `ptrs.data()`

Comment: I see. But why I need to first declare a vector double of double and than another new double for than assign the first vector? Can't I just init one time?

Comment: Ok. But I just can't assign vector of double double without iterate it (the for)?

Comment: I mean, can't I not use `samplesContainer` and allocate a double of (N) in ptrs[i]? Or can't I use std::vector<double*> ptrs(M); and use samplesContainer for the first-level indexes?

Comment: any ideas please? I don't get why you init "two times".

Answer (score -1):

`samplesContainer.data()` returns `double*`, bur expression `*pSamples[N]` is of type `double`, not `double*`. I think you wanted `pSamples[N]`.

```
pSamples[N] = samplesContainer.data();
```